# std sort vector with nested private structs and own compare function

Tags: c++, sorting, stl

i have the following class

```
class foo{
    private:
    struct bar{
        double rng;
        ...
    };
    struct baz{
        bar abar;
        ...
    };
    void foobar();
    static bool cmp(baz a, baz b);
    ...
};
```

the cmp function does following:

```
bool foo::cmp(baz a, baz b){
    return (a.abar.rng < b.abar.rng);
}
```

now i want to sort inside the foobar function:

```
void foo::foobar(){
    std::vector<baz> aVec;
    // fill aVec
    std::sort(aVec.begin(), aVec.end(), cmp);
}
```

this gives many compile errors, the first is:

```
> stl_algo.h: no match for call to '(__gnu_cxx::_normal_iterator<foo::baz*,
> std::vector<foo::baz> >) (foo::baz&, foo::baz&)'
```

What's wrong?

Comment: The code you show compiles fine with g++ 4.6.3. Please include an SSCCE (http://www.sscce.org).

Comment: First of all, `bool foo::cmp(baz const& a, baz const& b)` is the signature you want here. Indeed this could be the problem if the copy-constructor of `baz` is private.

Comment: Compile on gcc 4.8.1 : http://ideone.com/p2LjoV

Comment: Also compile fine with gcc 4.7.2, it would help to know which compiler the OP is using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your real code, it looks like you're passing the iterator instead of the comparison function:

> `(__gnu_cxx::_normal_iterator<foo::baz*, std::vector<foo::baz> >) (foo::baz&, foo::baz&)'`

It's trying to *call* the iterator with the elements to compare. That doesn't work.

The code you showed gets it right, though: http://ideone.com/pwo5Cu

Comment: yeah the error was in how i used the sort. it was different than in my example. now it compiles.

Comment: @MichaGlu I can't help but wonder why you wasted our time asking a question with the wrong code sample. Please make sure to always include code which reproduced the actual error in your future questions.

Answer (score 0):

The code you shows compiles fine. At a guess, in your actual code `cmp` resolves to something other than `foo::cmp`, giving rise to the error in question.